# find in vector of struct

Tags: c++, algorithm, find

I have a struct and two vectors like this

```
struct CodeColor
{
 int index;
 string color;
};


std::vector<CodeColor> secret_code;
std::vector<CodeColor> my_code;
```

I need to search in each item from `my_code` in `secret_code`. What I need to get is, for each item in `my_code`

1. Is there a item in `secret_code` that match both `index` and `color`.
2. If not, is there a item only match `color`
3. Not any of above two.

Actually I can do this by two for loops, but I don't like to do in that way (considering time complexity). I'm trying to use `find_if` or any other way. any suggestion?

Comment: Are you allowed to have repeated CodeColors in the vectors?

Comment: Yes, color repeated there

Comment: @ Karoly Horvath: So how to do?

Comment: Is `index` really separate from the vector element index?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function similar to the function in this demonstrative example Vector secret_code is looked through only once.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct CodeColor
{
    int index;
    std::string color;
};

enum class SEARCH_RESULT { NO_MATCH, PARTIAL_MATCH, EXACT_MATCH };

SEARCH_RESULT find( const std::vector<CodeColor> &v, const CodeColor &value )
{
    SEARCH_RESULT result = SEARCH_RESULT::NO_MATCH;

    auto it = std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(),
                            [&value]( const CodeColor &c ) 
                            {
                                return ( c.color == value.color );
                            } );

    if ( it != v.end() )
    {
        result = SEARCH_RESULT::PARTIAL_MATCH;
        it = std::find_if( it, v.end(),
                           [&value]( const CodeColor &c ) 
                           {
                            return ( c.index == value.index &&
                                     c.color == value.color );
                           } );
        if ( it != v.end() ) result = SEARCH_RESULT::EXACT_MATCH;
    }

    return result;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<CodeColor> secret_code = 
    { 
        { 1, "Red" }, { 2, "Green" }, { 3, "Blue" }
    };

    std::vector<CodeColor> my_code =
    {
        { 2, "Green" }, { 1, "Blue" }
    };

    for ( const CodeColor &c : my_code )
    {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>( find( secret_code, c ) ) << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
2 1
```

You can rewrite the function such a way that it would return a pair of an enumerator and a corresponding iterator.

Comment: But find_if is O(N), it's O(N^2), and OP was trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Will Briggs I never said whether there is O( N^2 ) or O( N ). I showed how in one loop to determine whether there is a match.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this approach:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>

set<CodeColor> intersect;
set_intersection(secret_code.begin(),secret_code.end(),my_code.begin(),my_code.end(), // sorted!
                  std::inserter(intersect,intersect.begin()));
```

In this approach,

```
template< class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt >
OutputIt set_intersection( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                           InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                           OutputIt d_first );
```

Constructs a sorted range beginning at d_first consisting of elements that are found in both sorted ranges [first1, last1) and [first2, last2). The first version expects both input ranges to be sorted with operator<
So, you need to overload `< operator` for `CodeColor`

Comment: Nice solution! Won't this need some operator overloading on `CodeColor`?

Comment: @Debasish Jana, could you explain a bit?

Comment: Operator < should be overloaded for CodeColor

Comment: OP still have to then distinguish between *2.* and *3.*, i.e. partial match with color and no match.

Comment: @Jarod42 in that case two different sets of set_intersection needs to be found, in one, comparison based on both color and index and in second comparison based on other criteria with customized compare function supplied as additional last argument

Comment: The set_intersection is linear -- O(total size of both sets) -- and creating the sets will be O(N log N) for each set -- so I'd say OP's got his wish with this answer.